# Let the extention $GF(p^m) \supset GF(p)$ that contains roots of $p(x)=x^{p^{m}}-1$. Show that those roots are distinct and that forms a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I want to rewrite a question not so well written on this site and clarified by Mr. Lahtonen (thank you again).

So here the question:

> Let the extention $GF(p^m) \supset GF(p)$ that contains roots of
>   $p(x)=x^{p^{m}}-1$. Show that those roots are distinct and that forms
>   a field

I know that the roots of $p(x)=x^{p^{}}-1$ are contained in $p(x)=x^{p^{m}}-1$, but then?

edit: probably the correct exercise was $p(x)=x^{p^{m}-1}$

Comment: I am sorry, but as is, $p(x)=(x-1)^{p^m}$.

Comment: Mmm that because $(x-1)^{p^{m}} = x^{p^{m}}-1 \pmod p$, right?

Comment: Yes indeed... did you mean $x^{p^m-1}-1$?

Comment: You mean in the question text?

Comment: Yes: since your polynomial $p$ is a power of an affine polynomial, it cannot have distinct roots. However, if $p$ instead means $x^{p^m-1}-1$ then your statement holds.

Comment: This is an exercise from my course and I think probably there is an error and it's indeed $x^{p^{m}-1}$, that let me rethink the whole thing! Thanks!

Comment: @Mindlack in this way, from the definition of order of $GF(p^m)$ descend that there are ${p^{m}}-1$ distinct solutions, wich are the elements $\alpha$ of the field itself. And those form the fundamental subcyclic field $\subset$  $GF(p^m)$. Is the proof complete now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you understood the proof completely or approximately, so I will include a full proof.

$P(X)=X^{p^m-1}-1$ vanishes at every nonzero point of the field, and there are $p^m-1$ of them. So the product of all $X-a$, where $a$ runs through all nonzero elements of the field, whoch we denote as $Q$, has degree $p^m-1$ and divides $P$. Since $P$ and $Q$ are monic and have the same degree, they are equal. Thus the root of $XP$ are pairwise distinct and are exactly the elements of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the splitting field 
$E=GF(p^m)$ of $f(x)=x^{p^m}-x$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

We will show that $|E|=p^m.$ Since $f(x)$ splits in $E$, we know that $f(x)$ has exactly
$p^m$ zeros in $E$, counting multiplicity. Moreover, by the Theorem

> A polynomial $f(x)$ over a field $F$ has a multiple zero in some
>   extension $E$ if and only if $f(x)$ and $f^{'}(x)$ have a common factor of
>   positive degree in $F[x]$.(Refer Gallian Theorem $20.5$ for the proof)

Every zero of $f(x)$ has multiplicity $1$.
Because $f^{'}(x)=p^mx^{p^m-1}-1=0.x^{p^m-1}-1=-1$ Thus $f(x)$ and $f^{'}(x)$ does not have any common factor of positive degree.
 Thus, $f(x)$ has $p^m$ **distinct zeros** in $E=GF(p^m)$

On the other hand, the set of zeros of $f(x)$ in $E$ is closed under addition,
subtraction, multiplication, and division by nonzero elements so that the set of zeros of $f(x)$ is itself an extension field of
$Z_p$ in which $f(x)$ splits. Thus, the set of zeros of $f(x)$ is $E$ and, therefore,
$|E|=p^m$.